# JMX Monitoring for Kubernetes scaling Statefulset

Tags: java, kubernetes, jmx, azure-aks, amazon-eks

I'm trying to get JMX monitoring from jconsole for an application that is running inside a Kubernetes pod.

Currently, I'm following this method:

I expose a port, let's say 5000 in the YAML

I create a nodePort service that binds that pod port to the worker nodes port

I add the following 4 java properties:

```
JMX_REMOTE_AUTHENTICATE

JMX_REMOTE_PORT

JMX_REMOTE_RMI_PORT

JMX_REMOTE_SSL
```

Then I can go into a monitoring tool like jvisualvm and create a connection to the public IP of the worker node hosting that pod at port 5000 and I can monitor that pod, which works great.

Issue:
Now let's say my application scales up, and a new pod comes up on another worker node, I can manually add all the above steps again to monitor that pod.

But that isn't ideal. Ideally, I'd like every pod to be automatically get monitored as it comes online. I can add the properties for JMX in my statefulset YAML, but do I need a nodePort service for every single pod that comes online that binds to a different port? If so, there must be a way to do this through a script or a built-in function?

Anyone with any experience with this, any pointers would be very helpful?

Comment: I would consider adding prometheus or a similar system to your stack. Prometheus can auto-discover metric endpoints to collect, including JMX by including an annotation on the pod. It runs inside your cluster, so you don't need to worry about things like creating a nodeport service.

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud providor? It is important to reproduce your problem.